# How to get previous tag name?

Tags: git

There are some tags:

```
first
second
third
fourth
```

I need to get the tag before "second" (third).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 second^`

Comment: thanks. that's what i need just `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags second^`

Comment: on git version 2.5.0: fatal: Not a valid object name second^

Comment: Did you just copy the command or do you actually have a tag "second"?

Comment: what could be the reason if I am not getting correct tag. In my case I can see the tag in the output of `tag list` but above command gets me previous to previous tag somehow. if git tag returns
```
0.44.0
0.45.0
0.47.0
```
and i  run the command `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags 0.47.0^` i get `0.44.0` instead of `0.45.0`

Comment: Check the revision tree using `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`. It is possible that you have a merge commit and `0.45.0` comes from one branch while `0.47.0^` chooses the other. You might try `^0.47.0` in that case.

Comment: This command doesn't work on windows git doesn't recognize `second`

Comment: See comments above -- "second" is the placeholder -- you should use your own tag here.

Comment: Please add the `--tags` parameter, the command wouldn't work without it. I upvoted the comment mentioning that, but can't yet do the same to the answer at the moment 

Answer (score 9):

Or between the last two tags

```
git log $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags $(git describe --abbrev=0)^)...$(git describe --abbrev=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution with any sorting you like to get the next tag after the current one:

```sh
git tag --sort=-creatordate | grep -A 1 second | tail -n 1
```

1. `git tag --sort=-creatordate` prints all tags from newest to oldest by creator date: *"first second third fourth"*. Choose sorting option wisely.
2. `grep -A 1 second` filter only *"second"* and one following line after it, i.e *"third"*.
3. `tail -n 1` prints one last line from *"second third"* and we have finally get the *"third"*.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the hard way that the accepted answer to this question only finds tags reachable from the commit history for the branch you are on (which is fine for many use-cases).

I needed to get prior commit regardless of current branch history, so this solution worked more wholistically.

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-creatordate --format '%(refname:short)' refs/tags | sed -n '/second/{n;p;}'
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29835315)

Comment: I just tried that and it works fine for any branch. But you definitely need to have the tags locally, so probably `git fetch --tags` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Following command also can be used:

```
git tag --sort=-creatordate | head -n 3 | tail -n 2
```